# Why my app is crashing even though is very simple?

Tags: react-native, expo

I just created this most simple expo sdk48 app, but after it asks permissions about camera, it crashes, can someone tell me what's wrong with my setup? It's pretty basic, I started from an app containing just a view of the camera using `expo-camera` package and added one more subview containing just a bunch of simple components. when the app was containing only the camera, the app was not crashing, but when I added the extra components, it began to crash.

In Expo Go, the app works well, but after I build it and run it on android, it crashes.
can someone help me?

Oddly enough the bottombar displayed in a wrong position at the top, and then it asks for camera permissions, and for microphone permissions, I select yes/no, then boom crash. I guess it has something to do with expo-camera because when I don't give camera/mic permissions it doesn't crash.

in `App.js` :

```
 
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'; 
import { CameraScreen, BottomBar } from "./src/subviews"; 
 
export default function App() { 
  return ( 
    <> 
      <StatusBar style="auto" /> 
      <CameraScreen /> 
      <BottomBar /> 
    </> 
 
  ) 
}
```

in `CameraScreen.js`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'; 
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'; 
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'; 
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library'; 
 
 
export function CameraScreen() { 
    let cameraRef = useRef(); 
    const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(); 
    const [hasMediaLibraryPermission, setHasMediaLibraryPermission] = useState(); 
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(); 
 
    useEffect(() => { 
        (async () => { 
            const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync(); 
            const mediaLibraryPermission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync(); 
            setHasCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === "granted"); 
            setHasMediaLibraryPermission(mediaLibraryPermission.status === "granted"); 
        })(); 
    }, []); 
 
    if (hasCameraPermission === undefined) { 
        return <Text>Requesting permissions...</Text> 
    } else if (!hasCameraPermission) { 
        return <Text>Permission for camera not granted. Please change this in settings.</Text> 
    } 
 
    let takePic = async () => { 
        let options = { 
            quality: 1, 
            base64: true, 
            exif: false 
        }; 
 
        let newPhoto = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options); 
        setPhoto(newPhoto); 
    }; 
 
    if (photo) { 
        let sharePic = () => { 
            alert(photo.uri); 
        }; 
 
        let savePhoto = () => { 
            MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri).then(() => { 
                setPhoto(undefined); 
            }); 
        }; 
 
        return ( 
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
                <Image style={styles.preview} source={{ uri: "data:image/jpg;base64," + photo.base64 }} /> 
                <Button title="Share" onPress={sharePic} /> 
                {hasMediaLibraryPermission ? <Button title="Save" onPress={savePhoto} /> : undefined} 
                <Button title="Discard" onPress={() => setPhoto(undefined)} /> 
            </SafeAreaView> 
        ); 
    } 
 
    return ( 
        <Camera style={styles.container} ref={cameraRef}> 
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}> 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePic} > 
                    <View style={styles.circle_3}></View> 
                    <View style={styles.circle_container}> 
                        <View style={styles.circle_2}></View> 
                        <View style={styles.circle_1}></View> 
                    </View> 
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View> 
        </Camera> 
    ); 
} 
 
const BASE_SIZE = 100 
const OFFSET = 7.5 
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    container: { 
        flex: 1, 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
    }, 
    buttonContainer: { 
        backgroundColor: '#fff', 
        alignSelf: 'center', 
        margin: '30%', 
        borderRadius: '50%' 
    }, 
    preview: { 
        alignSelf: 'stretch', 
        flex: 1 
    }, 
    circle_1: { 
        top: OFFSET, 
        right: OFFSET, 
        // position: 'absolute', 
        width: BASE_SIZE, 
        height: BASE_SIZE, 
        borderRadius: BASE_SIZE / 2, 
        backgroundColor: '#ae2012', 
    }, 
    circle_2: { 
        top: OFFSET / 2, 
        right: OFFSET / 2, 
        position: 'absolute', 
        width: BASE_SIZE + OFFSET, 
        height: BASE_SIZE + OFFSET, 
        borderRadius: (BASE_SIZE) / 2,
backgroundColor: '#fff', 
    }, 
    circle_3: { 
        position: 'absolute', 
        width: BASE_SIZE + OFFSET + OFFSET, 
        height: BASE_SIZE + OFFSET + OFFSET, 
        borderRadius: '50%', 
        backgroundColor: '#ae2012', 
    }, 
    circle_container: { right: -2 * OFFSET } 
});
```

in `BottomBar.js`

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { View, FlatList, Text, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'; 
import { Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
 
const labelProps = { 
    size: 24, 
    color: '#83c5be' 
} 
const bottomtabs = [ 
    { key: 1, label: <Feather name="users"  {...labelProps} /> }, 
    { key: 2, label: <AntDesign name="message1" {...labelProps} /> }, 
    { key: 3, label: <AntDesign name="camerao"{...labelProps} /> }, 
    { key: 4, label: <Octicons name="three-bars" {...labelProps} /> }, 
] 
 
export const BottomBar = () => { 
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => { 
        return ( 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert()}> 
                <View 
                    style={{ 
                        display: 'flex', 
                        justifyContent: 'center', 
                        alignItems: 'center', 
                        backgroundColor: '#000', 
                        height: 80, 
                        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width / bottomtabs.length 
                    }}> 
                    <Text key={item.key}> 
                        {item.label} 
                    </Text> 
                </View> 
            </TouchableOpacity> 
 
        ); 
    }; 
 
    return ( 
        <View> 
            <FlatList 
                data={bottomtabs} 
                renderItem={renderItem} 
                horizontal={true} 
            // ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ margin: 1 }} />} 
            /> 
        </View> 
    ) 
}
```

my `package.json`

```
{ 
    "name": "estudocamera", 
    "version": "1.0.0", 
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js", 
    "scripts": { 
      "start": "expo start", 
      "android": "expo start --android", 
      "ios": "expo start --ios", 
      "web": "expo start --web", 
      "b": "eas build --profile production --platform android" 
    }, 
    "dependencies": { 
      "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0", 
      "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1", 
      "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11", 
      "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6", 
      "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12", 
      "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16", 
      "expo": "~48.0.15", 
      "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.3.2", 
      "expo-camera": "~13.2.1", 
      "expo-media-library": "~15.2.3", 
      "expo-speech": "~11.1.1", 
      "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4", 
      "react": "18.2.0", 
      "react-dom": "18.2.0", 
      "react-native": "0.71.8", 
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.1", 
      "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4", 
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0", 
      "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0", 
      "react-native-web": "~0.18.10" 
    }, 
    "devDependencies": { 
      "@babel/core": "^7.20.0" 
    }, 
    "private": true 
  }
```

Comment: it turns out the problems might be related to the Stylesheet, one of them would be setting percentage unit for `borderRadius`